# Servlet getParameter from url and the value is int

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to modify a record from a database
After clicking update a record
the url like http://localhost:8080/Phonebook/index.do?action=update&uid=7
noted that I am using Netbeans with Tomcat to run the servlet

and i would like to retrieve the value uid in order to update a record

in the servlet code

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
int uid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("uid"));

pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE phonebook SET Name= ?, Phone=? where UID = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, name);
pstmt.setString(2, phone);
pstmt.setInt(3, uid);
```

i run it

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [JDBCServlet] in context with path [/Phonebook] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

how can i solve it?
thanks

Comment: if you are sure you are passing a number in url then try trimming the string maybe there is some extra space

Comment: You must not be using the URL you showed us. Or you are doing something else you aren't showing us.

Comment: your URL is wrong one please show us correct one.

Comment: the problem is that in the prepareStatement, I cannot set the value of uid properly

I am using netbeans with Tomcat to run it and the URL is 
http://localhost:8080/Phonebook/index.do?action=update&uid=7

Comment: What is your column type in database. never mind.

Comment: can you try printing all the 3 values